# I want to connect my NodeMcu v3 to gsm

Tags: arduino-ide, gsm, nodemcu

I have a problem with connecting my NodeMcu to gsm. I have bought GSM module but I have sim code on card which I can't and that is the problem because I've found some libraries but there are no examples how to connect with pin code. I have found one but not compatible with NodeMcu. How can I do It?

Comment: put the card in a phone and remove the PIN

Comment: It's not possible